# Could not extract ResultSet while using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to extract result set from my database using Spring Boot and Spring Data jpa. When I am applying jpa query I am getting the following error in my Postman application:

```
{
"timestamp": "2020-09-25T06:28:05.202+0000",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "Parameter value element [{0=com.spacestudy.model.Users@2357844c}] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [{0=com.spacestudy.model.Users@2357844c}] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]",
"path": "/spacestudy/rockefeller/security/retrieveUserByNotRoleAssigned"
}
```

and in my STS editor console, I am getting the following message,

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [{0=com.spacestudy.model.Users@2357844c}] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)
```

My repository **UserRepository.java** is codded like the following,

```
@Query("select new map(u.nuserId,u.susername) from Users u where u.nuserId NOT IN :userRoleMappingList")
List<Users> findByUsersNotassignedRole(@Param(value = "userRoleMappingList") List<Integer> userRoleMappingList);
```

And my service, I wrote like the following,

```
public List<Users> retrieveUsersByNotassignedRoles() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    List<Integer> userRoleMappingList = userRoleMappingRepoObj.findByUserId();
    
    return userRepoObj.findByUsersNotassignedRole(userRoleMappingList);
 }
```

and **UserRoleMappingRepository.java** coded with,

```
@Query("select new map(ur.nuserId) from UserRoleMapping ur")
List<Integer> findByUserId();
```

Where did I go in the wrong direction?

Comment: Parameters are prefixed with colon in the query

Comment: @RoyalBg - Yes , I added colon, But error is still there.

Comment: But now the error is different - about type mismatch. You are trying to search integer in a list of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

userRoleMappingList should be a list of userIds.

Comment: Yes. Its only returning list of User Ids. I modified the in the question.

Comment: From your error it seems that userRoleMappingList  has "Users" object and not the userId.

List<UserRoleMapping> userRoleMappingList should be List<Integer>

Comment: I am using "select new map(ur.nuserId) from UserRoleMapping ur" query in my UserRoleMappingRepository.

Comment: List<UserRoleMapping> userRoleMappingList should be List<Integer> userRoleMappingList

Comment: Yes. I modified like same with Integer. But error is still there. I modified the updated code.